# How to write const ref without allowing temporary creation

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects

I want to be able to supply functions which take an **existing** object of a given type **by const reference**.

i.e. I want by-const-ref-but-no-temporaries-created. [edited this phrase to clarify it!]

I can't think of any way to express that in C++ directly:

1 `void fn(const T & t)`
will create a temporary `T` from an `S` if a (non-explicit) `T(S)` exists.

2 `void fn(T & t)`
will only allow a non-const `t` as an argument (I need this to work for const `t`'s as well).

3 `void fn(T && t)`
requires a non-const `rvalue`.

4 `void fn(const T && t)`
requires a `const rvalue`

Is there any way to do this - accept any argument by reference, const, without allowing a temp to be created?

---

Failed thoughts:

Supplying #2 and #4 without supply the other two, and now we have an unambiguous `fn` that takes a reference to any existing `T` (but won't silently generate a temporary)?

Nope, that isn't adequate either, because I need to also be able to bind to a `const T &` - Where the target object is itself been passed in by const reference to our caller...

---

I guess I see no way to achieve this except in the case where I can control `T` to ensure it doesn't supply an implicit `T(S)`.

Am I right, or am I overlooking some solution?

Comment: `void fn(const T & t)` + `void fn(const T && t) = delete` should do the trick. Alternatively put a `static_assert` there to explain to people why they have to give the temporary that they want to pass in a name.

Comment: Why would you want to disallow temporaries anyway?

Comment: What do you want to do in your function?

Comment: Our code base extensively uses MFC's CString - which have CString(const char-type *) non-explicit ctors.  This makes it trivial to accidentally have functions which take `const CString &` actually create a temporary CString on the spot - which can be insanely poor performance (when you notice it), or just a drag when you don't.
So I want various free fn's which take CString's if they're already a CString, but plz don't create a temp if they aren't (generate an error!)

Comment: FWIW, these are in fact free functions in my actual use case.

Comment: Below you wrote: "I'm only trying to avoid fn(t) silently converting a non-t to a t". This is completely different to your actual question, which is all about rvalues and lvalues (all of type `T`). Maybe you need to do some clarifying.

Comment: You should look into replacing `const CString &` with something like [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question - it was my fundamental confusion (and hence need to ask!) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the comments, it seems like your *actual* question has nothing to do with rvalues and lvalues, but simply preventing implicit conversions. You can do this by changing the function to a function template, and then constraining the template with sfinae:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, CString>::value, int> = 0>
void fn(const T&) {

}
```

This will only work if called with some kind of `CString`, a type that implicit converts to a `CString` will not work.

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80602c39cdc4d35e

That said, a better solution would simply be to change those functions to accept a `string_view`, which can be cheaply implicitly constructed from various kinds of strings. I don't know if it handles `CString` or not, but you can always right your own. It's a fairly simple class to write. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view

Comment: Indeed - I was flailing for an answer without knowing where to look.  SFINAE sounds like a promising approach.

Comment: I've been waiting what feels like centuries for a good string_view and ranges - but I have not had the time to see if they're actually good enough for my use yet?  I'll definitely take a look (and writing adaptors for `CString`s is no problem)

Comment: @Mordachai There may be some annoyances because you basically lose any member functions of `CString`, if it's like `std::string` then that's a lot. But typically you can do something similar with standard algorithms or a for loop. Other than that though it's pretty trivial; a string view is just two pointers, one to the beginning, one to the end. Some const-correct begin and end members. And a few implicit constructors. You can write something good enough for your use in probably 100 lines of code.

Comment: thanks for the info - yeah, I've had the idea of a string view forever - but I desperately want std::range to become a thing so that it can be done correctly and not as a hackish thing.  The entire standard library should have been written with views (ranges) from the very start - and then rich range-adaptors / view-adaptors.  As it is, it's pretty dumb (but getting better).
In my case here - even a view is dumber than what I want - which is "compiler - when you see get_length(CString), this is the **most efficient way to resolve that**

Comment: @Mordachai To be clear, you don't need ranges in any way to have a nice solution for this. `string_view` will be standardized without ranges. Ranges are mostly just necessary for nice composition which isn't what's going on here.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a free function then you can do as [nwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484570/nwp) suggests and add an overload taking a rvalue reference and deleting it.

```
void fn(const SomeType& t)
{
    // stuff to do with const lvalue
}

void fn(SomeType&&) = delete; // compiler error if you give me an rvalue
```

This works because a rvalue reference is preferred over a reference to `const`.  So when overload resolution kicks in and you pass a temporary the compiler will select `void fn(const T&&)` as the best match.  After that it will see that the function is deleted and it will issue a compiler error

Comment: Ugh!  I wish this worked for all of my actual use-cases!  So close!
But, in my case, I also want to allow this: `fn(fm())` - where `fm()` returns a `T` - but in this circumstance, it is a `const rvalue` but the choice to generate a `const rvalue` was explicitly reasonable in the code.  I'm only trying to avoid `fn(t)` silently converting a non-`t` to a `t`... :(

Comment: @Mordachai Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43122779/4342498) I just wrote on a related question could help.  I'm not sure though on how exactly to tie them together.  I'll need to think about this some more.

Comment: @Mordachai I also had a bug in the code.  It should have been `void fn(SomeType&&) = delete;` and not `void fn(const SomeType&&) = delete;`.

Comment: Even the corrected non-const rvalue version of your solution fails for me due to my needing to allow `f(g())` where `g()` returns a `T` (in this Q's parlance).  Hence, in that case, an rvalue is perfectly reasonable - it isn't being induced - it is already there by-definition, explicitly.  I do wonder if there is some template magic to distinguish such a case - all non-`T`'s from actual `T`'s... maybe that is a fruitful thought....