# Function templates: extern template vs explicit specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, extern

Consider the following function template declaration:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>>>
void foo(T i);
```

There is only one possible valid instantiation of this template, namely with `T = int`. I'd like to put this definition in an implementation file. I can think of two possible ways of doing so. (If you're wondering why on earth I'd do this rather than just saying `void foo(int i)`, it's because the template version prevents implicit conversions at the call site.)

**Approach 1:**

I can use an `extern template` declaration to tell other TUs that `foo<int>()` is instantiated elsewhere:

```
// In foo.hpp
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>>>
void foo(T i);

extern template void foo(int);

// In foo.cpp
template <typename T, typename>
void foo(T i) { ... } // full template definition

template void foo(int); // explicit instantiation with T = int
```

**Approach 2:**

I can provide an explicit specialisation for the `int` case:

```
// In foo.hpp
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>>>
void foo(T i);

template <> void foo(int i); // explicit specialisation declaration (*)

// In foo.cpp
template <>
void foo(int i) { ... } // explicit specialisation definition
```

**Questions:**

- Are both of these approaches legal, or am I unintentionally relying on UB?
- If both are legal, is there a good reason to prefer one approach over the other, other than the fact that approach 2 is very slightly less typing? Both GCC and Clang work equally well with either approach.
- For approach 2, is the explicit specialisation declaration at `(*)` actually required? Again, both GCC and Clang are perfectly happy if it's omitted, but doing so makes me uncomfortable about the fact that a call to `foo(3)` in another TU is an implicit instantiation of a template with no definition visible, and no promise that such a definition exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

There is a third approach.  In approach 3 you specify the function you want to have and the you add a template overload and mark that as `delete`.  That looks like

```
void foo(int i)
{
    // stuff
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) = delete;
```

Since the template version will match all types exactly it will be preferred in all cases except `int` since a non template exact match is preferred to a template one.  So you will only be able to call `foo` with an `int` and all other types will give you an error that they are trying to call the deleted function `void foo(T t)`.

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aced9e5c90e204d1)</kbd>

Comment: isn't the code ill formed because of [temp.res/8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8.1)?

Comment: @W.F. As far as I know it is not for that reason and according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716589/force-function-to-be-called-only-with-specific-types) a compiler error is the expected result.